# Display radio buttons depending on a constant

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, button, components

I want to display a number of radio buttons that equal the const total_regions. I would like to give each one a differnt value.
 E.g if total_regions = 5, then five radio buttons are displayed with values 1 - 5.

```
import React from 'react';

const Test = props => {

  const total_regions = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.test)).length); // gets the number of regions

  return (
    <ul>
      {props.test.map(item => {
        return <li>{item.length}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>                  
    );
  };
export default Test;
```

I played around with the props trying to get somewhere but I don't know how to print each button for each entry with a specific value. Could I turn total_regions into a array and use mapping with it

App.js:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import React from "react";
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import LeftPane from "./components/LeftPane.js";
import Video from "./components/Video.js";
import Footer from "./components/Footer.js";
import Test from "./components/Test.js";
//import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { apiResponse: [] };

  }
  // Comunicate with API
  callAPI() {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/IntensityAPI") //React app talks to API at this url
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }));
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.callAPI();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <div class="row fixed-top fixed-bottom no-gutters"  >
            <div class="col-3 fixed-top fixed-bottom">
              <LeftPane></LeftPane>
            </div>
            <div class="offset-md-3 fixed-top fixed-bottom" >
              <Video></Video>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-3 fixed-bottom">
          //  <Footer test = {this.state.apiResponse}/>
          <Test test = {this.state.apiResponse}/>
            </div>      
            </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: added my attempt there

Comment: What is `props.test` here? can you please share some data related to it also. And how using `<li>{item.length}</li>` are you trying to create radio button??

Comment: just render a radio instead of the li, no ?

Comment: @palaѕн added my app.js would u like to see the json file? I using list to mess aorund with it and see if any output was happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to loop over the data and return a radio button for each item in the data, I've made an example sandbox for you to look at. Hope it helps :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-water-c0ihx?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `index` parameter of the array::map function and map to a radio type input

```
{props.test.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <label key={index}>
      {item}
      <input type="radio" value={index} />
    </label>
  );
})}
```